# android intent chooser - display chooser with one option

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I want to create an intent choose to show only one option (copy to clipboard), but when I do it, The intent is automatically started (copied to clipboard) and no chooser is displayed.
here is my code:

```
Intent copyToClipboard = new Intent(activity, ShareToClipboardActivity.class);
copyToClipboard.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, entry.getEntryShareLink());
LabeledIntent labeledCopyToClipboard = new LabeledIntent(copyToClipboard, activity.getPackageName(), "Copy!", 0);
List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(labeledCopyToClipboard, activity.getPackageName(), "Copy to clipboard", R.drawable.ic_content_copy_gray_24dp));

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(new LabeledIntent(labeledCopyToClipboard, activity.getPackageName(), "Copy to clipboard", R.drawable.ic_content_copy_gray_24dp), "Share entry");
activity.startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

can someone please advise?

Comment: Why do you need an intent chooser then in the first place? Make a button, onclick it copies to clipboard, wont it do?

Comment: because the chooser is built in runtime, so sometimes it has only one option, sometimes more...

Comment: So what does it matter? It copies to clipboard. Ready. Done!

Comment: because the user does not know what happened

Comment: are the any updates, solutions, workarounds for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

something is fishy! am i being paranoid or you defined nested intent in these two line of your code? are this necessary?

```
LabeledIntent labeledCopyToClipboard = new LabeledIntent(copyToClipboard, activity.getPackageName(), "Copy!", 0);

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(new LabeledIntent(labeledCopyToClipboard, activity.getPackageName(), "Copy to clipboard", R.drawable.ic_content_copy_gray_24dp), "Share entry");
```

Comment: yes, one is the actual intent, the other is for displaying in the chooser

Comment: you add labeledCopyToClipboard to intentList. you startacticity with new LabeledIntent. what's the use of intentList?